# Include .inc file for my own module

Tags: 6

I have written my own module for example called: calc
and i have used `module_load_include('inc', 'calc', 'form.inc')` in my calc.module file,
and placed form.inc file inside my module's directory: calc/form.inc but it doesn't see that file. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be:

```
module_load_include('inc', 'calc', 'form');
```

(The 'inc' in the first argument automagically appends as the extension)

Answer (score 3):

With `module_load_include('inc', 'calc', 'form.inc')` you are including the form.inc.inc file present in the directory where the calc.module file is present.

If you want to include the form.inc file in that directory, you need to use `module_load_include('inc', 'calc', 'form')`, as Jimajamma said.

The first argument of [module_load_include()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/6) is `$type`, the second is `$module`, and the third is `$name`. They are concatenated together using the following code.

```
$file = './' . drupal_get_path('module', $module) . "/$name.$type";
```

When you don't pass `$name` to the function, it will use for `$name` the same value passed for `$module`.

You could also include a relative path in `$name`, such as `'includes/form'`; in that case the loaded file would be `'includes/form.inc'`, where includes is a directory contained in the directory containing the module whose name is passed as second argument.

Comment: Thanks, I was just testing `if (module_load_include('inc', 'calc', 'form')) { print 'included'; }`, and it was giving me nothing, but then I tried `if (module_load_include('inc', 'calc', 'form') !== FALSE {print 'it worked!'; }`.

Comment: That's right: The function returns `FALSE` only when the file to include is not found, or it is a directory; when the file exists, it returns nothing.